# .Net Intermittent System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

We have a .net 3.5 web app that consumes third party web services. The proxy was created by adding a web reference to their wsdl. This proxy is not compiled.

Our error logging is picking up frequent but intermittent exceptions:

An exception of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException' occurred and was caught

If I follow the url to the page that generated the exception, I can't recreate it.

**Edit: Here is most of the exception - where it bubbled up from**

```
Message : Internal Error
Type : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException, System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a Source : System.Web.Services Help link : 
Actor : 
Code : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Client
Detail : 
Lang : 
Node : 
Role : 
SubCode : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : System.Object[] ReadResponse(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage, System.Net.WebResponse, System.IO.Stream, Boolean)
Stack Trace :    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Vendor.getSearch(getSearchRequest getSearchRequest) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\be43c34e\b09edc7e\App_WebReferences.pww-cf-q.0.cs:line 73
```

**Edit 2: Inner exceptions:**

I sometimes get the following inner exceptions logged:

```
Message : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    Type : System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    Source : System
    Help link : 
    Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
    TargetSite : Int32 Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
    Stack Trace :    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
       at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
       at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
```

And/Or:

```
Message : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        Type : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        Source : System
        Help link : 
        ErrorCode : 10054
        SocketErrorCode : ConnectionReset
        NativeErrorCode : 10054
        Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
        TargetSite : Int32 Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)
        Stack Trace :    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
           at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

**Update**

We're still working on it. Originally there was a route issue, which was resolved. We're still getting the inner exception with socket errors. We had MS support involved today, and they looked at some traces and network captures. The web service host does round-robin DNS, and they may be responding on a different IP address for the syn syn/ack from one ip, and the next from a different ip. This is not good. This is likely quite specific to our situation, but perhaps it applies to others as well.

Microsoft Network Monitor and an application trace got us the information we needed.

Comment: Could you provide the details of the exception (i.e. the exception message)?

Comment: Turns out that most of the exceptions were due to dns issues...sometimes it's just not programming related!

Comment: What was the solution to the DNS issues? We are having a similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian - I've added an update above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is is that while reading the beginning of the response from the server (the SOAP headers that are at the start of the response), the server instead of sending a SOAP response, closed the TCP/IP connection.

Obviously the error is not on the client side. It is most likely a **server overload** situation where instead of serving a response or a 500 or 503 HTTP error code it simply terminates the TCP/IP connection. There is a (very small) probability that some network equipment is causing these connection drops, but I would naturally start investigating the server side first.

I recommend using a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to log one of these errors. Since it's a forced TCP/IP connection close, I would look for communications with the server that end with TCP RST packet that forces the connection to close.

Comment: Looks like this is indeed a network / router issue. I'll post any results once we verify.

Answer (score 1):

This exception comes from the server side through SOAP headers and your client is probably not at fault here. You might get more info about this error from those 3rd party web service providers.

Comment: That will be tough. They have yet to admit responsibility for any issues thus far.

Answer (score 1):

We recently ran into this with our own web services and it ended up being a timeout issue. The actual timeout of the web service was set high enough and never getting hit, but it was throwing this exception because it was not giving any updates to stay alive (non-pumping). This was the solution for us, hope it helps. You can subclasss your web service or put this straight into the reference.cs file, but it gets overwritten when you update web references.

```
public partial class TheWebServiceSubClass : TheWebService
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        webRequest.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version10;
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

Comment: We added our web reference to a normal website project, so we don't have the reference.cs / vb file to edit. I could create a web app project for just the web reference to get access to this, but do you know another way? Thanks for the answer - I've seen this mentioned as a possible cause.

Comment: If you have them in VS as a web reference you can expand it to get the .cs file, but if not you can sub class it like i mentioned in the response. I'll edit the response with the subclass style.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the server is working properly, the fact that it included the `Client` code in the fault indicates that the server believes the client is at fault.

Are you passing SOAP Headers to the service? Then look to see if it's possible you're doing it incorrectly? Perhaps you're meant to be passing headers but sometimes you don't?

Comment: What's the best way to see what's being passed to the web service? Wireshark?

Comment: Why would the exact same request work only sometimes then? Are there any geographic / ISP issues that would cause these requests to get mangled?

Comment: @ScottE: You would have to ask the server why it sometimes works and sometimes fails - it's the server that's returning the fault. Maybe the server is flipping a coin? Probably not, but that illustrates that the problem could be entirely within the server, and entirely invisible without "asking" the service what's wrong with it.

Comment: @John, what kinds of things can go wrong in my situation? httpKeepAlives? threads getting eaten up by the web requests/responses? Where do I start?

Comment: @ScottE: Start with the Windows event log on the server machine. If it's a WCF service, then turn on tracing. This is a "normal" debug situation (on the server). You have to go hunt for anything unusual happening at the time of the error.

Comment: Nope, it's not WCF. I don't think it's even .net. The wsdl had to be added as a web reference as well, not as a service reference.

Comment: Sorry John, but this answer really isn't helpful.

Comment: @ScottE: The fact that the error is from the client doesn't help you?

Comment: No. It's of course the client, the server, or the combination of client and server. I've upvoted answers below that give a possible solution, or at least some more information. I'm not sure why your answer was upvoted, and at the time it didn't seem right that you would be automatically chosen as correct.

Comment: @ScottE: No. The "`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Client`" code means that the server believes it's a client problem. That code is part of the SOAP standard. It's not just random.

Comment: When you say 'client', are you talking about whoever is browsing the site, or about the 3rd party that publishes the web service?

Comment: @ScottE: client, as in client/server. The client that sent the request to the service. The service then replies with a SOAP Fault with the Code element set to `Client`. BTW, it might be clearer if you were to post the result of `ex.ToString()` instead of breaking the exception down.

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions you are seeing might be caused by errors in your server side code.

It looks like the exception occurred in `Vendor.getSearch`.  What code does this method contain?

Comment: .getSearch is a method invoked from the 3rd party web service. There are no errors in the server side code - this is intermittent.

Comment: That it is intermittent doesn't mean there is no server side error. Intermittent errors are sometimes seen because the things are changing (passing in different data, or different users, etc). It may have to do with different data being passed in. I need more information in order to help you. What are you sending to the service?

Comment: I'm sending in different search parameters. I've tried following the links from the page that generated the error (which has all the params in the querystring) and NOT received the error. I've only once been able to get an error screen, and that in itself was intermittent. I feel that the issue has to do with load - specifically that the ws requests take about 500 ms to come back. I think threads are getting chewed up - one for the request and one for the response. I don't know how to confirm this, however. I guess I'm looking at the best way to diagnose the issue.

Comment: It really seems like its a server problem.  The best way to diagnose would be to have the cooperation of the server.